# Django model help

Tags: django, model

Does anyone have any clue why this doesn't work as expected.

If i use the python shell and do

```
team.game_set
```

or

```
team.games
```

It returns an error

```
AttributeError: 'Team' object has no attribute 'game'
```

If i create a Game object and call

```
game.home_team
```

it returns the correct team object

Heres my model

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_team")
```

UPDATE

I've updated the mode by removing the related_name and i now get this error

```
app.game: Accessor for field 'home_team' clashes with related field 'Team.game_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'home_team'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you set the `related_name` attribute. From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#arguments):

> **ForeignKey.related_name**
>   The **name to use for the relation from the *related* object back to this one**. See the [related objects documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for a full explanation and example. Note that you must set this value when defining relations on abstract models; and when you do so some special syntax is available.

So if you want to have access to the objects via. `team.game_set` you have to remove this parameter:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

or you access the games via the attribute `home_team` (but I guess you just misinterpreted the meaning of `related_name`):

```
team.home_team
```

---

If your class is going to have a `guest_team` attribute or multiple relationships to `Team` in general, you have to set a related name and might want to have something like this:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_games")
    guest_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="guest_games")
```

and then you can access the games via `team.home_games` and `team.guest_games`.

Comment: @dotty: Are these the full definitions of your classes? If you have multiple relationships to the same model you have to use `related_name` as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Well i have home_team and away_team, i guess using the home_games and away_games would work well.

Comment: Very well explained answer, thank you very much. Helped me understand related_name a lot more.